# how to get sms ringtone in android

Tags: android, notifications, sms, ringtone

I want to develop a messaging app . In this messaging app , the user can change the default sms ringtone . For this I have to show in a dialogue all sms ringtone . 
Whenever the user select the sms ringtone , the name of the sms ringtone will be set in a textview and the ringtone will be set as default sms ringtone . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Whichever you do it. This code will surely do stuff you want!!**

```
selsound_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{   
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        Uri currenturi = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 1l);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select ringtone for notifications:");
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, currenturi);
        startActivityForResult( intent, 999);   
    }
});


RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
myActivity, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, currenturi);
```

**Well Adding in your manifest file is a must**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

uri is not the name of the name of the rigntone

```
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri); 
String title = ringtone.getTitle(this);
```

use it as convinient to you

Comment: What is the currenturi ? What code I have to write in onActivityResult ?

Comment: I have edited...whatever you need to do, you have to do onActivityResult

Comment: How can I set this ringtone as default sms ringtone ?

Comment: I am getting exception for setting default ringtone .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96022/discussion-between-johnrao07-and-osimer-pothe).

Comment: How can I set ringtone name in textview ?

Comment: create a custom layout for the listview

Comment: When user selects ringtone , I have to set ringtone name in a textview . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would offer the user a preferences screen. There is a special entry for Rintones: [`<RingtonePreference />`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference.html)

```
<PreferenceScreen>
    <RingtonePreference
         android:title="Current Ringtone"
         android:key="ring" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

After using that property the rintone will been saved in your preferences with the key `ring`.

If you don't want to use a preferences screen you can use the intent which the ui aboves uses internally:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
startActivityForResult(intent, 4711);
```

Start that intent with a result code and check it in your onActivityResult like here:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 4711) {
        if(data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            if(uri != null) {
                yourTextView.setText(uri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never used a preferences screen?

Comment: No , I never use preferences .

Comment: In that case lean about them in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) and please use the new [compat library](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceScreen.html).

Comment: How can I get list of sms ringtone ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri defaultRintoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), defaultRintoneUri);
```